# ASP.NET MVC Set and Get Values for fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After learning ASP.NET WebForms, I am now trying to learn ASP.NET MVC.

I'm trying to figure out how to set and get values from a textbox in MVC. In WebForms, the way I would achieve this would be...

**Create the Control**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="myClass"></asp:TextBox>
```

**In the .cs File**

To set a text in the Textbox I could do this...

```
txtFirstName.Text = "hello world";
```

To get value from Textbox I could do this...

```
string text = txtFirstName.Text;
```

**Now in MVC it's different...**

I learned that all HTML code goes in .cshtml file and you place the backend code elsewhere...

This is currently where my HTML code resides.

Views > Home > Index.cshtml

```
<input class="myClass" id="txt_first_name" type="text" name="txt_first_name"/>
```

How do I achieve the same task in MVC as I do in WebForms?

Comment: A key element of MVC is Razor.  You really should read up on that.  Things like textboxes can be written as `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeTextField)`

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out

Comment: To get values from c# into the html you use razor (mostly).  To get values from the html back to c# (on the server) you have a couple of options: form post, ajax, or a url encoded get are the main ones.

Comment: Okay, hmm l'll try to search for some tutorials for the things you mentioned.